# Flashing texts and links when moving mouse on/off an image in explore cities section in Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

In Careers on the main page, when one moves the mouse on or off an image in the *explore cities* section the text of the link itself changes its style several times. Furthermore all links of cities "after" the hovered city do so and all the text in the right column.

```
City 0 | City 1 | City 2
City 3 | City 4 | City 5
```

"After" in this case means that if you, e.g., hover City 2, the link of City 2 and all cities after City 2 (so 3-5) change their style several times.

I use Safari 7.1 on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.5), but did not test with other browsers, so it may be browser specific.

It is just a minor and design/style bug, but it is quite weird that this happens and does not look right.

The problem also occurs in Safari 8 on Yosemite:

[image]

Comment: @AlexWarren Thanks for the image. This is exactly how it looks like on my machine. (Safari 7.1, Mac OS X Mavericks/10.9.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Mike's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242311/flashing-texts-and-links-when-moving-mouse-on-off-an-image-in-explore-cities-sec#comment795532_242340) this is now fixed.

Some CSS trickery has been performed to prevent Safari from doing its weird GPU compositing thing, which was causing unrelated parts of the page to re-render.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here seems to be related to CSS transforms *and* opacity transitions being applied to the `<img>` tag. I removed the opacity transition from the image tag, opting to use an empty overlay `<div>` instead for the darker overlay on hover. This fix should be pushed out onto production later today.

Comment: For me this did not fix the bug. Said texts/links still flash and also now all city names flash instead of only the name of the hovered city and the ones after it.

Comment: @Nero --- I can't repro this problem. I am running OS Mavericks. I have tested this in Chrome 38, Safari 8, and IE 10.

Comment: @Hynes I can reproduce this in Safari 8 - I've edited the question with an animated gif screenshot. Bold text appears to become un-bold during the transition - may be a Safari bug I suppose?

Comment: Additionally, GPU compositing issues are in play. The browser seems to be handling all the city page images, and the sidebar, in a single compositing Render Layer. Fix is in prod.